# Assumption behind Gibbs Energy and maximum work

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

So, I've asked this question in Chemistry Stack Exchange but received no response yet. So I'm gonna try here.

[image]
I'm somewhat confused by this derivation (in Schroeder's Book of Thermal Physics) of the fact that in a closed system, the change in the Gibbs Energy is always less than the Non-Expansion work done on the system.

If we take the change in the entropy of the universe (system + ideal surroundings maintained at constant temperature and pressure also assuming that reactions are taking place in system only i.e. the composition of various species present in surroundings remain constant), then it turns out (in this derivation) that it equals to negative of change in Gibbs Energy divided by Temp of system (which is same as that of surroundings).

Now since entropy of Universe always increases it turns out that Gibbs Energy of system will always decrease. But this is only true in absence of Non-Expansion work.

However during this derivation nowhere it's mentioned that 'no non expansion work assumed' yet the result only holds true in absence of non expansion work.

Same also holds for Helmholz Free Energy. Here we can see it's assumed that no P-V work is done on system (volume constant) still the final result comes out that it should always decrease. But I'd expect to get more general result that change in Helmholz Energy is always less than 'other' types of work performed on system.

I think that maybe it was assumed somewhere and I'm not able to spot where. How it's possible that without assuming anything about non expansion work the finally result holds only true in the absence of non expansion work? Please help me to clear my doubt.

Comment: Hi Shivansh, it's against our rules to post images of text you want to quote. Please type it out instead so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulas, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136).

Answer (score 0):

In the derivation of equation (5.29) the steps go,
\begin{equation}
dS_{total}=dS+dS_{R}=dS+\frac{dU_{R}}{T}
\end{equation}
The next step replaces $dU_{R}$ by $-dU$. In other words, the derivation leading to equation (5.29) assumes $dU+dU_{R}=0$. However, suppose that a mechanical system does some non $P-V$ work $dW$ on the system plus reservoir,
\begin{equation}
dW=dU+dU_{R}
\end{equation}
But, we've already seen that the steps leading to equation (5.29) require $dU+dU_{R}=0$ . So, this is the point in the derivation leading to equation (5.29) that the writer has made the assumption that the external mechanism is not doing any work on the system plus reservoir.

Comment: But here we are assuming that the system and the reservoir are completely isolated so there can be no external agency that can do work on them. (That's why in this derivation entropy of surroundings is assumed to increase). My confusion is the case where the reservoir does non expansion work on the system. In that case dU + dUr = 0.

Comment: @ShivanshJ : The theorems about the change in a  thermodynamic potential being less than the work done refer to work done by an external mechanical system not work done by the reservoir on the thermodynamic system

Comment: Stephen Blake: I got the answer from chemistry stack exchange. Actually the equation 5.27 (Thermodynamic identity) which can be used to find the entropy change of the system assumes absence of non expansion work. In case of non expansion work we need to add additional terms in that equation.

Comment: @ShivanshJ : The writer applied equation (5.27) to the reservoir, not the thermodynamic system. The thermodynamic system was written $dU$ without splitting it into changes in heat, PV work and other types of work.